# How can I evaluate a model with PyTorch Lightning over multiple DataLoader epochs?

Tags: pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

In the documentation of Pytorch Lightning there is written, that the Trainer.evaluate() and Trainer.test() evaluates the model on a single DataLoader epoch.

I have data, that are structured in such a way, that they can be split into groups. I want to evaluate the model for each group separately, but also globally.

Currently, I can have each group of data in a separate epoch of the test dataloader, but since the Trainer.test() method only evaluates a single epoch, I am not able to combine the calculated metrics into a single one.

Is there any easy way to somehow use the Trainer.test() method to evaluate the model over multiple DataLoader epochs and log the metrics globally and for each epoch separately?